# Spikes on IGBT's turn-on waveforms

Tags: gate-driving, waveform, igbt, spike

Here are the ideal IGBT turn-on waveforms and the actual waveforms from my own gate driver.

What causes the spikes on the actual waveforms at t0?

[image]

Idealized gate turn-on waveforms[image]

IGBT Turn-on waveform (yellow: input pulse, Blue Gate Voltage; Time Scale 1.00us)

Comment: A photograph of the actual arrangement in space would add information. Ch 1 is gate driver input potential? Or output before gate resistor?

Comment: @greybeard obviously input, because there is delay, and voltage levels are different.

Comment: (I had SGS-Thomson  [Application note 2123 on IGBT gate drive](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an2123-td351-advanced-igbt-driver-principles-of-operation-and-application-stmicroelectronics.pdf) found for me. Funny it would show that pronounced on the gate driver input - how is that driven, btw?)

Comment: Consider the effect of the stray inductance of the cable between driver and IGBT.

Comment: Try adding a schematic of your circuit showing all components and cables (if used).

Answer (score 1):

It's due to the inrush of current from the gate driver to the IGBT gate.  That current causes a spike in the supply. What you see there is not the actual voltage, it is an artifact. That spike generates an induced current in the scope probe's cable's shield which the scope shows as a positive pulse. To prove that to yourself, try connecting the tip of the scope probe to the ground of the same probe. Instead of the flat 0 V you'd expect, you will see that same pulse. That proves it's an artifact.

It's complicated. The current flowing through the non-0 inductance of real-world conductors generates a voltage pulse. Pulses are capacitively and magnetically coupled to other conductors. There may be a ground loop between the circuit under test and a grounded scope, and even if the scope is not grounded, it is capacitively coupled to earth.

The solutions are:

1. Proper grounding of the scope
2. Careful routing of the inrush current from the bypass capacitor across the gate driver, through the gate driver, through the Gate-Emitter of the IGBT
3. Proper sizing and quality of the bypass capacitor across the gate driver

Comment: It's... eh, not a great explanation, I mean: you're not completely right, but also not completely wrong (given currently available information). A better explanation is considering the inductance of both the gate *and return (emitter)* leads, which I assume have some length, and that the scope has been grounded to the IGBT, not the driver. This explains the "inrush" being rate sensitive (dI/dt, not I), and it's probably not the driver's supply being disturbed. Scope CM may or may not show the disturbance.